# Mix use of Emacs and macOS key bindings in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Is there any easy way to mix Emacs-like key bindings and macOS-like key bindings in PyCharm Professional 2019.2 for macOS?

The Emacs keymap provided with PyCharm enables `Ctrl-P,` `Ctrl-S,` `Ctrl-K,` and so on. But it disables ``` ⌘-N,``⌘-P, ``` and other macOS-like shortcuts. One of the advantages of macOS is that `Ctrl-XX` and `⌘-XX` can be used at the same time, enabling a wide variety of keyboard shortcuts. However, The Emacs keymap in PyCharm is different from what I want.

Ideally, `Ctrl-K` and `Ctrl-Y` should not use the system clipboard (i.e., only `⌘-C` and `⌘-V` should access it). Instead, they should access a dedicated memory buffer.